# Two Way Data-binding is not Updating for ComboBox & ToggleButton?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, .net-4.5, two-way

## Problem

I have a `ComboBox` and a `ToggleButton` on `MainWindow` with two-way bindings on their `SelectedIndex` and `IsChecked` properties, respectively. The properties they bind to are DependencyProperties (DP) and I have a breakpoint on the setters but the debugger never stops at either. I should note that the bindings should work as the Initialisers on the DPs work and converters also work. Also nothing of concern is VS's Output Window.

## XAML

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="tbSortDirection" Width="25" IsChecked="{Binding Path=SortDirection,Converter={StaticResource LDB},Mode=TwoWay,ElementName=mwa,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <ed:RegularPolygon Fill="#FF080808" Height="5" UseLayoutRounding="True" Margin="-2,0,0,0" PointCount="3" Width="6"/>
</ToggleButton>                 
<ComboBox x:Name="cbSort" Width="100" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="-5,0,0,0"  SelectedIndex="{Binding SelSortIndex,Mode=TwoWay,ElementName=mwa,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" >
    <ComboBoxItem Content="a"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="b"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="v"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="f"/>
</ComboBox>
```

## Code-Behind (DPs)

```
public ListSortDirection SortDirection
{
    get { return (ListSortDirection)GetValue(SortDirectionProperty); }
    set // BreakPoint here
    {
        MessageBox.Show("");
        SetValue(SortDirectionProperty, value);
        UpdateSort();
    }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty SortDirectionProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("SortDirection", typeof(ListSortDirection), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(ListSortDirection.Ascending));



public int SelSortIndex
{
    get { return (int)GetValue(SelSortIndexProperty); }
    set // BreakPoint here
    {
        MessageBox.Show("");
        SetValue(SelSortIndexProperty, value);
        UpdateSort();
    }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty SelSortIndexProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("SelSortIndex", typeof(int), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(1));
```

Comment: Try removing the extra stuff in your Dependency Properties' setters. Just have then call `SetValue` and give it another shot.

Comment: Still doesn't break. Is it supposed to break on the setters? Because the debugger doesn't break on the getters? I'm going to create a new test project and see if it is supposed to.

Comment: Does the converter ever get called? Note that when you use `Path` and `ElementName` in a binding, it'll look for that path in the specified element, not in the DataContext. So in the case of your CheckBox, it looks for `mwa.SortDirection`. What is `mwa` anyway? Is it your `MainWindow`?

Comment: yh mwa is MainWindow and the Converter works for the ToggleButton, debugger stops at the breakpoint. I created a temp project and looks like the getters and setters are not called on bindings.

Comment: Wait I'm confused. So it works fine for the `ToggleButton` but not for the `ComboBox`?

Comment: Only the ToggleButton has a converter and that works. When their properties change I want to call UpdateSort() but the debugger doesn't stop at their setters as it looks like it doesn't get called. Just realised I could set a `PropertyChangedCallback` in the code behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will not break as WPF will call directly `GetValue` and `SetValue` on `DependencyProperty`. If you want to do something when property changes then you need to define callback for when property is changed:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SortDirectionProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("SortDirection", 
                                 typeof(ListSortDirection), 
                                 typeof(MainWindow), 
                                 new PropertyMetadata(ListSortDirection.Ascending, SortDirectionPropertyChangedCallback));

private static void SortDirectionPropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
   (d as MainWindow).SortDirectionPropertyChangedCallback(e);
}

private void SortDirectionPropertyChangedCallback(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
   UpdateSort();
}

public ListSortDirection SortDirection
{
    get { return (ListSortDirection)GetValue(SortDirectionProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SortDirectionProperty, value); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you actually calling the setters?

For instance, saying

```
SortDirection = someOtherSortDirection;
```

would go into your setter, but

```
SortDirection.SomeProperty = something;
```

actually goes through your getter.

Set a breakpoint in your getter and I wouldn't be surprised if it's being called when you think your setter should be.

Comment: The Debugger isn't stopping at the getters either.